# Firebase Admin SDK - Current Logged In User - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-admin

How do i get currentUser in firebase admin SDK. In client SDK we can use

```
onAuthStateChanged() or firebase.auth().currentUser()
```

In NodeJs `Server.js` file firebase admin SDK **onAuthStateChanged()** Do not work, what should work here?

Basically i want only logged in users to access my innerPages so i am using express,nodejs **app.get** method to create routes.

```
app.get('/', authenticationRequired ,function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});
```

And trying to write **authenticationRequired** method (returns false or true depending on if user is logged in).

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: I have tried to getToken by `firebase.auth().getToken()` this error come up `Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined`

Comment: `firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK does not inherently know what user is using your Express web app. You will need to implement code for this. If you're already using Firebase Authentication in the web app, this takes these steps:

1. [Retrieve the user's ID token on the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients)

   You can get a user's ID token by using the `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()` method.
2. Pass this token from the client to the server
3. [Verify the token on the server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk)

   The user ID token can be verified using the `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)` method. On success it will return a promise with the `decodedToken`, otherwise it will return a rejected promise.

Comment: Thanks - this approach makes sense. Any advice for cases where we use rewrites in the firebase.json file to serve content directly from a cloud function? i.e. we don't show users a static page in which I can do the above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. still valid in 2019 with a minor change in a method name. In step 1 the method `getToken` has been renamed to `getIdToken`: `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()`

Comment: FYI, this article has code complete version of this https://fireship.io/snippets/express-middleware-auth-token-firebase/