# firebaseStore.auth().onAuthStateChanged is undefined when using firebaseAdmin in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, post

but `firebaseStore.auth()` is defined, and I enabled the password signin for the store. `onAuthStateChanged` seems just disappeared.

I tried to execute this before the route gets established as well as in a router call after passing the firebase instance into it.

I wonder what else I can do further to debug this?

I found this article [Firebase Admin SDK - Current Logged In User - Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215019/firebase-admin-sdk-current-logged-in-user-nodejs)
But it did not help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to use [firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged)?

Comment: I wrote why there isn't `onAuthStateChanged` below. But it seems very much like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do that requires the concept of a "current user"? It might help if you [create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can see what you're trying to accomplish and where you are stuck.

Comment: @BobSnyder yes, I tried to use that on server side, because I want to just pass the user name and passwords to server and call onAuthStateChanged() to check if the user is valid, at all time. I realized it is a wrong approach.... I was trying to avoid loading firebase on the front end

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Admin SDK runs as an (unidentified) administrative user. It does not have the concept of a "current user" and thus does not implement `onAuthStateChanged`.

Comment: Ok, that's more clear now. So basically firebase has to run in the client side to identify logged in user. I was trying to run in the server side, so the client wont know all my keys and such.... is it necessary to hide my keys though? the one that I suppose to copy to client to initate the firebase app... or maybe I dont have to?

Comment: The values that Firebase tells you to put into your web page are just configuration data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public